# UT005023: Exception handling request to Parent was not null, but this component not related

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly

In order to overcome the problem that is described in the below link
http://drewdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/cforeach-with-jsf-could-ruin-your-day.html
we wrote below code

```
uiComponent.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().removeIf(child -> child.getId().startsWith("st"));
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(uiComponent.getClientId());
```

and we managed to implement the functionality that we wanted. That functionality was working for almost 2 years until we upgraded to wildfly 26. Now we get below exception

```
[0m[31m12:07:53,908 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /aaa/views/bbb.xhtml: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent was not null, but this component not related
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.eraseParent(UIComponentBase.java:3262)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.access$500(UIComponentBase.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2289)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2257)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:533)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:313)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:52)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:185)
..........
```

Any idea how we can overcome the new problem?

If we set parent to null at the component that we remove then it does not render the ui components that we want.

jsf v2.3 ,primefaces v10 and wildfly v26

Comment: I would need a more complete example of what you are doing but since that blog was from 2008 i feel like there has to be a better way to do what you are trying to do in 2022???

Comment: yes you are right that it might be a better way to do that but unfortunately in my case it has to be dome with the JSF approach. The functionality that I have implemented adds/removes dynamically uicomponents in the FacesContext. I just added the old link because it describes the problem that I had and the solution that I followed in order to overcome this problem (until the upgrade to wildfly 26).

Comment: The only related issue I found I am sure you did too was from 2011? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611072/java-lang-illegalstateexception-parent-was-not-null-but-this-component-not-rel